# Can't install xcb-utils-xrm library

Tags: compiling, make, i3-wm

I am trying to install [i3-gaps](https://github.com/Airblader/i3) which on `make`ing gives me the following error

```
../i3-gaps/src/config_parser.c:38:25: fatal error: xcb/xcb_xrm.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
src/i3.mk:61: recipe for target 'src/config_parser.o' failed
make: *** [src/config_parser.o] Error 1`
```

Turns out I need to install [xcb-utils-xrm](https://github.com/Airblader/xcb-util-xrm), but with this one when I run `./autogen.sh` I get:

```
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Autoheader
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --no-force
Makefile.am:35: error: 'pkgconfig_DATA' is used but 'pkgconfigdir' is undefined
Makefile.am:26: error: 'xcbinclude_HEADERS' is used but 'xcbincludedir' is undefined
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

How can I fix this? I'm using Xubuntu 16.04.1

Comment: did you manage it in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same issue with i3-gaps on Xenial. Turns out it was a dependency that didn't get installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libtool
```

You can then run through the setup again and should be good to go, unless you are missing more dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a similar problem, installing pkgconf has solve my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install pkgconf
```

Comment: how similar is your problem? If you mean that installing `pkgconf` helped you compile something, then this is not a very helpful answer, because OP may need all kinds of dependencies

Comment: I have encountered this problem on our own product and it similar in two points.
First, I have this incomprehensible error: 'pkgconfig_DATA' is used but 'pkgconfigdir' is undefined.
Second, I am also using xubuntu 16.04.1, by default pkgconf is not installed on this distribution.
@Zanna, I do not understand your remark, what does "OP" mean?

Comment: sorry, OP is the original poster, the person asking the question